# Qeustion about inscribed angle in a circle.

Tags: geometry

[image: circle]

I have a circle as shown in the figure. In my text book, the angle BAD is the sum of angles ACD and angle ADC. There might be a theorem that shows this in the book but I cannot find it. Why is this true? I found a theorem that says in any triangle, a exterior angle is greater than an interior angle that is not supplementary to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple proof, given that the angles of a triangle add to 180, as do BAD and DAC. So BAD = 180 - DAC. DAC = 180 - (ACD + ADC). Therefore BAD = 180 - (180 - (ACD + ADC)) = ACD + ADC.

Answer (score 1):

$\angle ADC\cong \angle ACD$, and by the triangle angle sum theorem and the figure ($m\angle DAC=90^\circ$), $m\angle ADC=m\angle ACD=45^\circ$. By the exterior angles theorem then, $\angle BAD=90^\circ=45^\circ+45^\circ=m\angle ADC+m\angle ACD$.